# Why does urllib.urlencode add square brackets and single quotes to my dict values?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a script that can parse a url and get the query params from it. So far I've mostly got it, but urllib.urlencode is adding square brackets and single quotes to my values when I think it shouldn't be. This is most likely a misunderstanding on my part, so if someone could explain why this happens and how to avoid it I would really appreciate it. Here is my script:

```
#/usr/bin/python
import urlparse
import urllib

url = 'https://mysite.com?Action=ParseUrl'
parsed_url = urlparse.urlparse(url)
query_params = urlparse.parse_qs(parsed_url.query)

query_string = urllib.urlencode(query_params)
print query_string
```

The resulting output is:

```
Action=%5B%27ParseUrl%27%5D
```

So you can see that the value of 'Action' has been surrounded by urlencoded [' '] characters. I would like the value of my query_string variable to be :

```
Action=ParseUrl
```

What can I do to my script to make this happen. I realize I could hack some sort of reg exp to remove the characters, but I would rather understand the fundamental reason of why this is not working the way I want it to so I can avoid this problem in the future.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm a little confused why you keep parsing your query string after running it through `urlparse`.  `parsed_url.query` is already in the format you need - a flat string.

Comment: If you are writing new code you should consider using `urllib.parse` etc.

Comment: "I'm a little confused why you keep parsing your query string after running it through urlparse. parsed_url.query is already in the format you need - a flat string."

Comment: Sorry, I meant to add more to that last comment. I need to create a data structure to hold multiple key value pairs. Although my example only has one key and value, ideally this script could accept many more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [documentation notes about `parse_qs`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs) (emphasis added):

> Parse a query string given as a string argument (data of type application/x-www-form-urlencoded). Data are returned as a dictionary. The dictionary keys are the unique query variable names and the values are **lists** of values for each name.

You can confirm this yourself:

```
>>> print query_params
{'Action': ['ParseUrl']}
```

Consider using `parse_qsl` instead. With that change, the rest of your script behaves as you intended.

Comment: To make this more clear, it is perfectly valid to have a url `'https://mysite.com?Action=ParseUrl&action=ParseSecondUrl'` so a dictionary with single values won't do. `parse_qsl` fixes this by returning a list `[('Action', 'ParseURL'), ('Action', 'ParseSecondUrl')]` which `urlencode` can handle.

Answer (score 3):

You have **two** options to making your code working

The first one is to pass `doseq=True` to urllib.urlencode

```
import urlparse
import urllib

url = 'https://mysite.com?Action=ParseUrl'
parsed_url = urlparse.urlparse(url)
query_params = urlparse.parse_qs(parsed_url.query)

query_string = urllib.urlencode(query_params,doseq=True)
print (query_string)
```

output

```
Action=ParseUrl
```

The second one mentioned by Rob Kennedy is to replace `parse_qs` by `parseql`

```
import urlparse
import urllib

url = 'https://mysite.com?Action=ParseUrl'
parsed_url = urlparse.urlparse(url)
query_params = urlparse.parse_qsl(parsed_url.query)

query_string = urllib.urlencode(query_params)
print (query_string)
```

output

```
Action=ParseUrl
```